# Trying access the jws token in middleware file. jws token alwasy undefine in middleware file

Tags: node.js, express, jwt, middleware

I'm having trouble accessing my jwt token in the middleware file. I'm getting a token. But when I decoded it using online (https://jwt.io/) it says Invalid Signature. But the decoded result shows the correct email and hash password. Here is the userController.js file. I'm using node.js and express.js for this project

```
export const signUp = async (req, res) => {
    const { email, password, fName, lName, confirmPassword } = req.body;
    try {
        const existingUser = await userModel.findOne({ email });
        if (existingUser)
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "User already exist" });

        if (password !== confirmPassword)
            return res.status(400).json({ message: "Password don't match" });

        const hashedPasswoed = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12);
        const result = await userModel.create({
            email,
            password: hashedPasswoed,
            name: `${fName} ${lName}`,
        });

        const token = jwt.sign({ email: result.email, id: result._id }, "test", {
            expiresIn: "1h",
        }); // secret = test

        res.status(200).json({ result, token });
    } catch (error) {
        res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
};
```

then I'm trying to access the above token in my middleware.js file.

```
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";

const authMiddleware = async (req, res, next) => {
    try {
        const res = req.headers.authorization; // always undefine
        // const res = //tryed this way also but undefine
            // req.body.token || req.query.token || req.headers["authorization"];

        const token = res.split(" ")[1];

        const isCustomeAuth = token.lenght < 500;

        let decodedData;
        if (token && isCustomeAuth) {
            decodedData = jwt.verify(token, "test");
            req.userId = decodedData.id;
        } else {
            decodedData = jwt.decode(token);
            req.userId = decodedData.sub;
        }

        next();
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
};

export default authMiddleware;
```

'res' always undefine. Please help me to access the token in middleware as I'm trying this for days and got nowhere

Comment: How does the client make the request with the JWT? Can you share the relevant client-side code, please?

Answer (score 0):

In the client-side API file, I added an API interceptor. Then it got fixed

```
API.interceptors.request.use((req) => {
  if (localStorage.getItem("profile")) {
    req.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${
      JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("profile")).token
    }`;
  }
}
```

Now I can access the `req.header.authorization` and use the split function.